# Excel formula stored in SQL Server table not working

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a SQL Server table column that contains excel formulas for the hyperlink to another sheet.

The data stored in the column is:

```
  =HYPERLINK("#'Graphs Tab 1'!A115", "This is link 1")
```

When I load data to excel sheet from SQL, the excel column shows the formula text and does not work.

It's only after I move focus to formula bar the text gets converted to formula.

In the following picture column, B2 has been converted to formula since I have focused on formula bar for it, whereas Column B3 as visible in the picture is an only text & not behaving like a link.

[image]

Comment: How are getting the data from SQL?

Comment: I am loading data from excel connection menu, Data > New Query > From Database > From SQL Server Database

Comment: I think You need to tell excel You want hyperlink, so maybe try to convert downloaded data into formulas in excel or use VBA? **Sub insert_hyperlink()
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("B2"), Address:="http://google.pl"
End Sub**